# Standardizing Sum of Uniform Distributions

Tags: statistical-inference, moment-generating-functions

Let X be a Unif(−6,6) variable, that is, X is Uniformly distributed over the interval (−6,6).

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be independent Unif(−6,6) variables. Let
$Y=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$

Find the mgf $M_Y(t)$ of Y. Evaluate the mgf at the point t=0.28 in the case n=5

so for this i know using the property of MGF it would be just multiples of the 5 IID MGFs

Standardize Y to create a new variable Z with mean zero and standard deviation 1. Find the mgf $M_Z(t)$ of Z. Evaluate $M_Z(t)$ at the point t=2.95 in the case n=11.

for this question how am I going to approach to this? could anyone give me some hints? It would be grateful if someone could guide me through this.

Answer (score 2):

for the first question, we go back to basics. For any one of the $X_i$, we have that the mgf of $X_i$ is equal to 
$$E(e^{tX_i}).$$
The density function of $X_i$ is $\frac{1}{12}$ on $(-6,6)$ and $0$ elsewhere. Thus
$$E(\exp(tX_i))=\int_{-6}^6 \frac{1}{12}e^{tx}\,dx.$$
Integrating, we find that the mgf is 
$$\frac{1}{12t}\left(e^{6t}-e^{-6t}\right).$$
Take the fifth power of this to find the mgf of $Y$.

For the second problem, we first need to find the mean and variance of $Y$. The mean is $0$ (good, there is nothing we need to do). For the variance of $Y$, this is equal to $5$ times the variance of any of the $X_i$.

The variance of the uniform on $(-6,6)$ is $\frac{1}{12}(6-(-6))^2$, that is, $12$. It follows that $Y$ has variance $60$.

Thus $Z=\dfrac{Y}{\sqrt{60}}$, since multiplying a random variable by $k$ multiplies the variance by $k^2$.

We found the moment generating function $M_Y(t)$ of $Y$. The moment generating function of $Z$ is given by 
$$M_Z(t)=M_Y(t/\sqrt{60}).$$

Comment: can you explain a bit more on the second problem? the way you approach it

Comment: Let $U$ and $V$ be random variables, with $V=kU$. Then $M_V(t)=E(\exp(tV))=E(\exp((kt)U)=M_U(kt)$.

Comment: Quite an excellent answer Andre, thank you!